# How to remove an added value by uncheck box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have check box to add a value on click. However, It also adds even if I unchecked the box. How can I remove the added value when I uncheck the box? Thank you!

```
$('.addCheckBox').click( function( event ){
                var btn = $(event.currentTarget);
                var Data = btn.data();
                var addList = $('#ListBtn');

                var Obj = {
                    aID: Data.id,
                    aName: Data.name
                };
                addList.push( Obj );
                addListBtn[0].innerHTML = "(" + addList.length + ") in List";
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.addCheckBox').click(function (event) {
    if ($('.addCheckBox').is(':checked')) {
        var btn = $(event.currentTarget);
        var Data = btn.data();
        var addList = $('#ListBtn');

        var Obj = {
            aID: Data.id,
            aName: Data.name
        };

        addList.push({"myData":Obj});
        console.log(addList);
    }else{
        var addList = $('#ListBtn');
        addList.remove("myData");
        console.log(addList);
    }
});
```

Comment: Careful! `Array.pop()` won't always do what the OP is looking for. Imagine you have many checkboxes: you have to remove exactly that object from the array.

Comment: Thanks! it does not add more value for uncheck. However, it won't remove the added value..

Comment: @user1781367 What are cahObj and addListBtn? which list you want to remove the item from?

Comment: the var Obj is what I want to remove. (sorry there was an type for Obj.)

Comment: @user1781367 is ListBtn a html control? or an array?

Comment: It's the HTML control

Comment: @user1781367, that's weird, but try the answer i just edited.

Comment: shouldn't myData be the var Obj ?

Comment: @user1781367 sorry, i missed the double quotes.

Comment: It doesn't do what I need in my case but your code looks good and clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("#checkBox").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            // if checked   add value
        }else{
            // if unchecked remove value
        }
    });
```